# What do the のに and ったら mean here?

Tags: grammar, manga

> だってあたしがダメだったのに神谷が言ったらさ

What do のに and ったら mean? Is のに like "even though" or "in order to" and ったら like "if" (that's what I thought about)? The other character asked to stop talking about a thing and this was the answer and it makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This のに is "but". のに meaning "in order to" does not follow the past tense for the obvious reason. たら in 神谷が言ったら means "when", but the result of 神谷's statement is not stated in this sentence.

So literally:

- だって
  You know / Come on
- あたしがダメだった
  I was not successful / I didn't make it
- のに
  but
- 神谷が言ったらさ
  when Kamiya said (something), you know, (something happened).

The context is missing, but this sentence sounds like people only listened to Kamiya even though the speaker and Kamiya said the same thing.

> (When I said something) I wasn't successful, but when Kamiya said (the same thing), you know, (people listened to him/her).

If this still doesn't make sense to you, please [provide the entire context](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2189/5010).

Comment: I thought のに meant "even though", that is it's stronger than "but".